# Question on AD Groups and Sharepoint Groups

Tags: security, active-directory, claims

I have a security group inside Active Directory called 'Services'.  I've added a number of users to the group.  I then went into Sharepoint and added that group to the 'Contribute' sharepoint group.  The group appeared in the intellisense so I figured all was fine.

But when I take a user who is part of the Active Directory group and click 'Check Permissions' inside Sharepoint, they aren't showing up with the rights that are granted to 'Contribute'.  I can add the users directory to the Sharepoint group, but that defeats the purpose of managing Sharepoint via AD.

I have set the claims authentication ticket to expire every two minutes and have waited over an hour.  I also did a full user synchronization to see if that would change anything but it didn't.

Is there another process that we can use to force the claims updates to refresh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Members of AD groups cannot be viewed by SharePoint (without code).  Therefore, when you check permissions, members of the group will show as having no rights.  Here is an article discussing this: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/active-directory-groups-vs--sharepoint-groups-for-user-management-a-dilemma.aspx

Comment: Hmm.  So if I check permissions on a user, they won't come up because the group is seen as a user.  That I get.  But if I give a group access to do something, and the user is part of that group, shouldn't they be able to use said permissions?

Comment: @user23915: yes, they will have the permissions but they won't show as having them in the "Check Permissions" feature. If the users are NOT effectively getting the permissions, then that is a different issue and you'll need to re-word your question accordingly to get a good response.

Comment: @Omegacron Thanks.  It looks like the user was continually requesting in the browser so their claims never updated.  The groups from AD are working inside the SP groups.